# What does kind undefined mean here? I cannot find any solution for this error

Tags: api, graphql, backend, apollo, apollo-server

I am trying to split up my schema of GraphQL API into separate ones. 
Having familiarized with a huge number of them I decided on this one below using "extend" 
*( I also wanted to use .graphql file extension for them but as I've got there is only one way to do that - it is with the use of webpack. I am not really good at it so I tried to make it work at first with .js files)*

**BUT**: I cannot cope with this simple task because I either have **TypeError: Cannot read property 'kind' of undefined** or **Invalid schema passed**, or something else pops up...

What am I doing wrong here and what is the best practice/approach to split up and stitch the Schema?

Thanks in advance!

**server.js**

```
import express from "express";
import { ApolloServer, gql } from "apollo-server-express";
import { makeExecutableSchema } from 'graphql-tools';
import * as mongoClient from "./config";
import * as _ from 'lodash';

import { UserSchema, UserResolvers } from "./graphql.partials/user.api";

const port = process.env.PORT || 8080;

const RootSchema = gql`

    type Query {
        _empty: String
    }

    type Mutation {
        _empty: String
    }
`

const RootResolvers = {
};


const app = express();


const schema = makeExecutableSchema({
    typeDefs: [RootSchema, UserSchema],
    resolvers: _.merge(RootResolvers, UserResolvers)
});


const apolloServer = new ApolloServer({ schema });
apolloServer.applyMiddleware({ app });


app.listen({ port }, () => {
    console.log(
        `Server ready at http://localhost:${port}${apolloServer.graphqlPath}`
    );
});
```

**user schema**

```
const { gql } = require("apollo-server-express");
import User from '../models/User';


export const typeDefs = gql`

extend type Query {
    users: [User]
    user(id: String): User
} 

extend type Mutation {
    addUser(email: String, password: String): User
    deleteUser(id: String!): User
    updateUser(user: UserInput): User
}

type User {
    id: ID!
    firstName: String
    lastName: String
    email: String!
    password: String!
    confirmed: Boolean
    role: String
}

input UserInput {
    id: ID!
    firstName: String
    lastName: String
    email: String
    password: String
    confirmed: Boolean
    role: String
}
`

export const UserResolvers = {
    Query: {
        users: async (obj, args, context, info) => {
            try {
                const res = await User.find();
                return res;
            } catch (err) {
                return err.message;
            }
        },
        user: async (obj, args, context, info) => {
            try {
                const res = User.findById(args['id']);
                return res;
            } catch (e) {
                return e.message;
            }
        }
    },

    Mutation: {
        addUser: async (obj, args, context, info) => {
            try {
                const res = await User.create(args);
                return res;
            } catch (err) {
                return err.message;
            }
        },
        deleteUser: async (obj, args, context, info) => {
            try {
                return User.findByIdAndDelete(args['id']);
            } catch (e) {
                return e.message;
            }
        },
        updateUser: async (obj, args, context, info) => {
            try {
                return User.findByIdAndUpdate(args.user.id, args.user)
            } catch (e) {
                return e.message;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Two tips unrelated to your question. One, you can use [a babel plugin](https://github.com/detrohutt/babel-plugin-import-graphql) instead of `graphql-tag`'s loader to import `.graphql` files. Two, you can have an "empty" type with no fields as long as you extend it. So instead of adding a dummy `_empty` field, you can just do `type Query` without the curly brackets.

Comment: @DanielRearden, does Babel support "extend" because now I am trying schema loader importSchema from graphql-import and it doesn't support it. It can only import completely different schemas without any extensions

Comment: It should. It just parses strings into DocumentNodes and type extension are standard GraphQL syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no export named `UserSchema` in your file. You have two named exports -- `UserResolvers` and `typeDefs`. As a result, when you attempt to import `UserSchema`, its value is undefined.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I checked it so many times and rearranged the code and played around with different approaches... you helped me a lot